# Pass the whole object to the cellFilter function in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

In ng-grid I need one of my columns to show a value that is dependent on multiple properties of my object. So I need to pass the whole object and not just one of its properties.

In another location of the project, I solved this by wrapping my objects in another object's say, `value` property, so for example one column was bound to `value.FirstName` and another one just to `value`.

Is there a way to avoid this warping, for example to just pass an empty `field` property, or just dropping the `field` property? Non of these methods seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not set a `field` and then use `row.entity` in the `cellTemplate`. Here is an example:

```
$scope.myData = [
  {
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    age: 43
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastName: 'Williams',
    age: 39
  }
];

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: myData,
  colDefs: [
    {
      displayName: 'Name',
      cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity.firstName}} {{row.entity.lastName}}</div>'
    },
    {
      displayName: 'Age',
      field: age
    }
  ]
};
```

This will result in a table like this:

```
+--------------+-----+
| Name         | Age |
+--------------+-----+
| Bob Smith    | 43  |
+--------------+-----+
| Joe Williams | 39  |
+--------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use row.entity object which can be referenced from any place of the cell template. It is linked to the whole object for the current row when building the grid.

Comment: Thank you, this method works. I had to accept Kabb5's answer as it contained more details.